# Can't Connect to SSIS Instance with Corresponding SQL Mgmt Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I have a fresh instance of SQL Sever 2017,
`Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 00:26:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)`

And v17.9.1 of SSMS. When I try to connect to the Integration Service I am receiving the following error:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to sqlprod.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "sqlprod" failed with the following error: "The specified service does not exist as an installed service.".

This error can occur when you try to connect to a SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service from the current version of the SQL Server tools. Instead, add folders to the service configuration file to let the local Integration Services service manage packages on the SQL Server 2005 instance.


For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506689

------------------------------

Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "sqlprod" failed with the following error: "The specified service does not exist as an installed service.".

This error can occur when you try to connect to a SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service from the current version of the SQL Server tools. Instead, add folders to the service configuration file to let the local Integration Services service manage packages on the SQL Server 2005 instance.


------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Why is my connection failing and why does it think it's a 2005 instance?

Also, here's my SSMS info:

[image]

Comment: Is the SSIS instance running? How comes you're connecting the the SSIS instance, and not using the SSIS Catalog instead?

Comment: The SSIS instance is running and we're still behind the curve and using the SSIS package store instead,

Answer (score 0):

You should get the SSMS version 16 from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/previous-sql-server-management-studio-releases install and connect to Integration Services instance.
BTW, this connection is kept for compatibility reasons with SSIS 2005-2008 packages. Starting from MS SQL 2012, SSIS supports so called Integration Catalogue, fully manageable from SSMS Database connection.

Comment: SSMS v16.5.3 gives the same message. I have a feeling it's down to the MDAC component I have installed (Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 10.0.18362.1) which I can't seem to roll back. Other devs who have yet to upgrade to Windows 10 are able to connect to our 2012 and 2017 SSIS instance fine.